# Convert string to variable in PHP

Tags: php, string, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a variable `$allrule = '(1 == 2) && (2 == 2)';`
when i check `if($allrule)`, it returns true because `$allrule` is treated as string. So i want to convert `$allrule` as condition of if statement. how can we do it.

Comment: Convert it to what? `$allrule` is a variable containing the string '(1 == 2) && (2 == 2)'.

Comment: You would have to use `evil()` or write some switch statements. But why do you want to do this?

Comment: Eval not evil @Rizier123

Comment: eval **IS** evil, @goikiu... it should never be used...

Comment: @Goikiu I know what I'm writing...

Comment: @JayBlanchard $allrule is string but i want this will run as a conditional statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution uses [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) which is pure [evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php), but since it wasn't stipulated not to do so...

```
$allrule = '(1 == 2) && (2 == 2)';
$result = eval("return (".$allrule.");"); // $result will be false
```

---

**Expanded Example*:**

```
$allrule = "(1433861812 > 1433694000) && (1433861812 > 1433771400) && (1433861812 > 1433944200)";

$result = eval("return (".$allrule.");");
if($result) {
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false"; // will echo "false"
}
```

*from comments

Comment: Provided solution is working fine but it return parse error.  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')'

Comment: What is your real $allrule? It might have an extra parentheses.

Comment: @Darkes My real $allrule =  "(1433861812 > 1433694000) && (1433861812 > 1433771400) && (1433861812 > 1433944200)";

Comment: @Darkes i modified it but it still gives me parse error; Can you provide the actual eval statement for provided string.   $allrule = "(1433861812 > 1433694000) && (1433861812 > 1433771400) && (1433861812 > 1433944200)"

Comment: Hello @RanjanKumar, I've added your allrule to my answer. Your allrule parses properly. (Please pardon the delay in my responding)